# Swapping operation in Tensorflow graphs

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given an initial graph, e.g.:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
var1 = tf.identity(tf.Variable(1.,))
y = x * var1
```

How can one change the flow to `y = x * var2`? Where `var2` is defined as:

```
var2_1, var2_2 = tf.Variable(2.,), tf.Variable(3.,)
var2 = var2_1 * var2_2
```

I would expect `tf.contrib.graph_editor.swap_outputs` to work, but it does not.

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
tf.contrib.graph_editor.swap_outputs(var1, var2) # swap var1 and var2
sess.run(y, {x:1})
```

Expecting output 6, getting 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

The trick is not to initialize a session before doing the swap:

```
tf.contrib.graph_editor.swap_outputs(var1, var2)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
sess.run(y, {x:1})
```